# using getoptiamlnewcameramatrix to recover all the original image

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2HZL.png)

this is my program output
and this is my distorted image[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEC5z.png)

to get the original image`s whole pixel ,I used the getoptimalnewcameramatrix,but the output is terrible ,my intrix and distcoffes is totally correct.
here is my program

```
Mat src = imread("E:\\40_office\\distorted_bot\\0.jpg");
    Size newsize(2280,3072);
    cout << src.rows;
    namedWindow("", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("", src);
    waitKey();
    Mat mapx,mapy;//size（x，y）

    Mat cameraMatrix = (Mat_<double>(3, 3) << 1224.1, 0, 761.7497, 0, 1209.8, 1043.6, 0, 0, 1);
    //Mat cameraMatrix = (Mat_<double>(3, 3) << 1224.1, 0, 1141.7497, 0, 1209.8, 1442.6, 0, 0, 1);
    //Mat cameraMatrix = (Mat_<double>(3, 3) << 1209.8, 0, 1043.6, 0, 1224.1, 761.7497, 0, 0, 1);
    Mat distCoeffs = (Mat_<double>(5, 1) << -0.3649, 0.1451, -0.0273, -0.000035214,0.0012);
    double alpha = 1;
    Mat newcameramatrix = getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, src.size(), alpha, newsize,0);
    cout << newcameramatrix<<"src.size"<<src.size();
    fisheye::initUndistortRectifyMap(cameraMatrix, distCoeffs,Mat(), newcameramatrix ,newsize, CV_16SC2, mapx,mapy);

    Mat newimage=Mat(newsize,CV_8UC3);

        remap(src, newimage, mapx, mapy, INTER_LINEAR);
        imwrite("C:\\Users\\wk\\Desktop\\1_cali100.jpg", newimage);

    return;
```

Comment: the original image size is 1520*2048,and i get a new size 2280*3072